# PHP-HTML-CSS - Internationalization and styling

Tags: php, html, css

So I have this function to translate everything on my Site using `GETTEXT`, this is my first time trying to do internationalization but this works fine.

However, it was in english when I created the stylesheet and in 15+ languages nothing fits where it's supposed to be.

So for instance I have a button `add to cart` but in German this is something like `in den Warenkorb legen` so it is overflowing the size of the button that I had styled.

Will I need to create a stylesheet for each language or is there some way to dynamically resize the translations to fit the containing element? I am not sure what best practices for this would be.

Comment: If you used fixed widths for everything then unfortunately you either need to create a style for each language or rewrite the styles to use a more responsive  sizing.

Comment: Well the first best practice to follow would perhaps be that you _don’t_ size elements such as buttons etc. explicitly, but let the content determine their width (plus possibly height). You can throw in a min- and max-width maybe (plus word-wrapping, hyphenation or what else might make sense.)

Comment: Yeah I thought I was making it as dynamic as possible, any widths were as percentages rather than a fixed pixel width, it's mainly stuff like menus and buttons though that are causing the issue, for example my menu system which goes across the top which had submenus is now overflowing onto a second line and the submenus for the first items on the first line are overlapping where it has dropped down a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stylesheet for each language is clearly unmaintainable. A responsive approach is a really better, I wont copy all the benefits so a give to you a [source](https://dzone.com/articles/7-reasons-why-is-responsive-web-design-matters).

Try to use an existing module in your favorite framework, lot a people have already do this.